# Add a script tag to the DOM including Angular code

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing an application that momentaneoulsy uses Angular, namely directives.
So at any moment I want to be able to through javascript add a script tag including my directive code.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
 s.type = 'text/javascript';
 s.src = 'path to directive file'
 $('body').append(s);
```

The file is loaded but never handled as Angular code. So in the page:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Is never transformed to the desired template.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's likely that the application has been already bootstrapped at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to bootstrap an AngularJS app: automatic or manual.

If you are using the `ng-app` directive in your markup, you are bootstrapping it automatically, and what you are attempting to do won't work, because the app is already initialized at that point.

Manually bootstrapping it might work in your case. I recommend you [read the docs on bootstrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).